# Correct structure of sentence

Tags: grammar

Can I write the given  sentence 'In life all do not succeed in the first attempt.' 
As
All do not succeed in the first attempt in life.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. You already did :) However, it does not sound quite right.

I would write something like: `In life, not everybody succeeds at the first attempt`.